# How to declare a polymorphic data interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to make an interface that represents my application data, basically my initial data object is :

```js
const data = {
  wallet: { ... },
  orders: [{ ... }, { ... }, ...],
}
```

`wallet` and `orders` are initial properties.
Now the data object can have volatile properties that represents cryptocurrency objects.
For instance the data object can be of this form :

```js
const data = {
  wallet: { ... },
  orders: [{ ... }, { ... }, ...],
  btc: { ... },
  eth: { ... },
  ...
}
```

Here's my typescript definition :

```js
export interface Data {
  wallet?: any
  orders?: Order[]
  [cryptoname:string]: CryptoObject
}
```

but typescript returns this exception :

> Property 'orders' of type 'Order[] | undefined' is not assignable to
>   string index type 'CryptoObject'.ts(2411)

What am I doing wrong ?

---

**EDIT:** I understand why I get this exception now. Typescript expects all the properties to be a `CryptoObject`.
My question is still opened because I wonder how to write the definition for this type of data structure.

Comment: Did you miss a semicolon somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

`[cryptoname: string]` is [an index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html#declaring-an-index-signature), which makes it so that:

> As soon as you have a string index signature, all explicit members must also conform to that index signature.

So by using an index signature here, you're saying that all members of your `Data` interface need to be `CryptoObject`s. Which is obviously incompatible with `Order[] | undefined`.

I don't really have an answer how to solve it for you except for adding individual members for each crypto you want to support. Like:

```
export interface Data {
  wallet?: any
  orders?: Order[]
  btc?: CryptoObject
  eth?: CryptoObject
}
```

Comment: I understand now why I have this exception. I'll wait and see if someone has a more extended solution. If not I'll implement yours. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I would use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
type Cryptos = 'btc' | 'eth'

type Data = {
    wallet?: any
} & Record<Cryptos, any>

const myData: Data = {
    wallet: 'foobar',
    btc: 123,
    eth: 456
}
```

See [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgTuYB7AzlAvFA5AI2AYyygB9sJgALLAKGtEigBEBDYZjKAb2ql6gHdmAGyHkA-AC4ozAHYhqAXygAyKACUI+JHAAmAHniJUAGmlyAfLS0yUwKAFsQLNlOftM3PgOGjgUrABmSEg4zHBYxjx8ePhSAIwATADMkV4A9GlQ5BRSACwArABsilZINkiiAHRCSADmABSObgCUQA). You can fiddle around with the exact definition of your intersection to get the best results. If you want to make your `Cryptos` optional, use `Partial<Record<Cryptos>>`.

<sub><sub>also don't use any please</sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Kyll answer. What I needed was [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)

```js
export type Data = {
  wallet?: any,
  orders?: Order[]
} & {[cryptoname:string]:CryptoObject}
```

Comment: Note that the main drawback compared to my solution is that given `myData` of type `Data`, `myData['foobar']` will yield a `CryptoObject` according to TypeScript, but not in the real world. Hence why I used an additional type which also has the benefits of 1) being able to export it for some other code to use it, 2) provide type-safety when getting the `CryptoObject`s and 3) provide auto-completion in your editor.